# Create replacement dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a secret code that I want to decode.

I've gotten a alpabeth not with letters, but with emojies. The first emoji is A, second is B, third is C etc:

```
 = A
 = B
❄ = C
⛄ = D
```

My entire emoji alpabeth is the following:

```
alphabet_emoji = "❄⛄✨"
```

Now I want to map each emoji to its letter using a dictionary.  I tried the following code:

```
replacement_dictionary[emoji] = str(letter);
```

However this gives me error:

> NameError: name 'replacement_dictionary' is not defined

My entire code:

```
# Input
alphabet_emoji = "❄⛄✨"
alphabet_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


# Connect emoji to alpabet
print("Length: " + str(len(alphabet_emoji)))
print("Emoji\tUnicode\tOccurrence\tLetter")
counter = Counter(alphabet_emoji)
x = 0
for emoji in alphabet_emoji:
    unicode = f'U+{ord(emoji):X}'
    occurrence = counter[emoji]
    letter = alphabet_uppercase[x]
    print(emoji + "\t" + unicode + "\t" + str(occurrence) + "\t" + letter)

    # Add to dictionary
    replacement_dictionary[emoji] = str(letter);


    # Counter
    x=x+1
```

**CODE THAT SOLVED THE PROBLEM WITH  Mr. Hobo COMMENT**

```
# Input
alphabet_emoji = "❄⛄✨"
alphabet_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


# Connect emoji to alpabet
print("\nHexmax A")
print("Length: " + str(len(alphabet_emoji)))
print("Emoji\tUnicode\tOccurrence\tLetter")
counter = Counter(alphabet_emoji)
replacement_dictionary = dict()
x = 0
for emoji in alphabet_emoji:
    unicode = f'U+{ord(emoji):X}'
    occurrence = counter[emoji]
    letter = alphabet_uppercase[x]
    print(emoji + "\t" + unicode + "\t" + str(occurrence) + "\t" + letter)

    # Add to dictionary
    replacement_dictionary[emoji] = str(letter);

    x = x+1
```

Comment: before for-loop, add `replacement_dictionary = dict()`

Comment: Unrelated: why is the alphabet only 16 chars long?

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Hobo. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never/did not define variable `replacement_dictionary`, yet you access(ed) it. Maybe this is the right code...

```
# Input
alphabet_emoji = "❄⛄✨"
alphabet_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


# Connect emoji to alpabet
print("Length: " + str(len(alphabet_emoji)))
print("Emoji\tUnicode\tOccurrence\tLetter")

counter = Counter(alphabet_emoji)

# Fixed here
replacement_dictionary = {}

# Loop(s)
for emoji in alphabet_emoji:
    unicode = f'U+{ord(emoji):X}'
    occurrence = counter[emoji]
    letter = alphabet_uppercase[x]
    
    print(emoji + "\t" + unicode + "\t" + str(occurrence) + "\t" + letter)
    
    # Add to dictionary
    replacement_dictionary[emoji] = str(letter);
```

Or if you want to use `**` instead of `replacement_dictionary[...]`, here is the code...

```
# Input
alphabet_emoji = "❄⛄✨"
alphabet_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


# Connect emoji to alpabet
print("Length: " + str(len(alphabet_emoji)))
print("Emoji\tUnicode\tOccurrence\tLetter")

counter = Counter(alphabet_emoji)

# Fixed here
replacement_dictionary = {}

# Loop(s)
for emoji in alphabet_emoji:
    unicode = f'U+{ord(emoji):X}'
    occurrence = counter[emoji]
    letter = alphabet_uppercase[x]
    
    print(emoji + "\t" + unicode + "\t" + str(occurrence) + "\t" + letter)
    
    # Add to dictionary
    replacement_dictionary = {emoji: str(letter), **replacement_dictionary};
```

Answer (score 0):

First define the dictionary;

```
your_dict = {}
```

OR

```
your_dict = dict()
```